# How to capture video in OpenCV 2.4 with Video4Linux2 (v4l2) in Qt 4.8 (C++)?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv, v4l2

I have Xubuntu 12.04.
My web camera, as I can see, does not provided by linux version of OpenCV 2.4, because in Windows XP (on the same machine) code

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0)
```

does not return NULL, but in Linux it does. I experimented with many arguments (many negative, many positive numbers and zero).

But other applications can capture video from my web camera in Linux.

I've tried to compile and run [this code](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/capture-example.html) and, I think, it runs good, because I can see dots, and I also can see some strange content of buffer (using -o key). I think, the content is frames, but I can't understand, how to use it (for example, create correct IplImage* from it).

How can I capture video from my web camera in Qt for further OpnenCV video processing?

And I also will need to capture video from several USB and IP cameras in one time.

The solution must be **free for commercial use**.

Answer (score 2):

You have to build OpenCV with v4l support. Take a look a this [guide](http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/). And make sure after configuring build you have this line:

> V4L/V4L2: Using libv4l

**Update:** after some googling I found that this is a bug. See [this thread](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/ubuntu-v4lv2-webcam-cvCaptureFromCAM-returns-NULL-td2497359.html) and try fix from the third post (use `LD_PRELOAD` or add `v4l1compat.so` to linker).

Comment: I do use WITH_V4L=TRUE. But I'll try to build OpenCV again.

Comment: I've done all according to the instruction. It does not solve my problem. It still returns NULL.

Comment: Yes. And I said it in my question. For example, Skype and Cheese are working perfectly with my camera. And test application, which is based on v4l2, works, but I can't understand, how to get frames from it and use them in OpenCV

Comment: I think, it is old...the posts are dated by 2009th year. And I even do not have a folder /usr/lib/libv4l/, and also file /usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so

Comment: if you don't have libv4l, you probably should install it. it's GPL, btw.